# Bind Label in Style to Property in styled object's DataContext

Tags: wpf, data-binding, styles

Condensed question:
In a WPF style, how do you access a Property in the data of the object you are styling?

```
style  ----- this access--------
   UI object                   |
      data                     |
        property{get;set;} <-- | Access this
      /data
   /UI object
/style
```

I have a ItemsControl which display's a bunch of polygons.

Code:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="TopVectorItemControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding TopVectorData}"
            SizeChanged="TimelineItemsControl_SizeChanged" MouseRightButtonUp="TimelineItemControl_MouseRightButtonUp">
<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <Common:ZoomableCanvas x:Name="TopAxis" Background="#FF65656C" Grid.Row="1" AllowDrop="True" IsVirtualizing="False"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="Polygon_DoubleClicked">
            <Polygon Points="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource PointsConverter}}" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Stroke="Black" 
                        Fill="{Binding DirectionProp, Converter={StaticResource FillConverterTopBottomAxis}}" />
        </ContentControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

When the user doubleclicks the polygon, I apply a style (these are adorners at each point on the polygon) to allow the user to change the shape/size of the polygon).

Style code:

```
<Style x:Key="ThumbStyleLeft" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="21">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="8"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Ellipse Width="8" Height="8" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1,1,0,0">
                    <Ellipse.Fill >
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" Opacity=".5"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <Label Content="000" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="7" Foreground="Black" Padding="0" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Picture:
[image]

Instead of "000", I need to set the Label's Content

```
<Label Content="000" Grid.Column="0" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="7" Foreground="Black" Padding="0" />
```

in the Style, to the Property:

```
public String TestingLabel {get;set;}
```

which is in the same Class and level as my binding to "Points" for my polygon's

```
<Polygon Points="{Binding Points, Converter={StaticResource PointsConverter}}" Tag="{Binding Tag}" Stroke="Black" Fill="{Binding DirectionProp, Converter={StaticResource FillConverterTopBottomAxis}}" />
```

How would I go about doing this?

I have tried:

**{TemplateBinding TestingLabel}**

**{Binding Path=TestingLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}**

without success.

Here is my code for adding the style to the thumbs:

```
public class AxisSelectionAdorners : Adorner
{
    private readonly Grid timelineGrid;
    private readonly ArrayList thumbArrray;
    private readonly TimelineItem timelineItem;
    private readonly VisualCollection visualChildren;

    public AxisSelectionAdorners(UIElement adornedElement, TimelineItem elementAt, Grid grid)
        : base(adornedElement)
    {
        thumbArrray = new ArrayList();
        visualChildren = new VisualCollection(this);

        timelineItem = elementAt;
        this.timelineGrid = grid;

        attachAdorners((Polygon)adornedElement);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        var adornedElement = this.AdornedElement as FrameworkElement;

        var polygon = (Polygon)adornedElement;
        var p = new Point();
        if (polygon != null)
        {
            Thumb thumb;
            for (int i = 0; i < polygon.Points.Count; i++)
            {
                p = polygon.Points[i];
                thumb = (Thumb)thumbArrray[i];
                if ((i == (int)TagId.Start) || (i == (int)TagId.FadeInEnd) || (i == (int)TagId.FadeInMag))
                {
                    thumb.Arrange(new Rect(p.X - 17, p.Y - 16, 22, 25));
                }
                else if ((i == (int)TagId.End) || (i == (int)TagId.FadeOutMag) || (i == (int)TagId.FadeOutStart))
                {
                    thumb.Arrange(new Rect(p.X - 5, p.Y - 16, 20, 25));
                }
                else
                {
                    thumb.Arrange(new Rect(p.X - 5, p.Y - 5, 10, 10));
                }
            }
            p.X = (polygon.Points[(int)TagId.End].X - polygon.Points[(int)TagId.Start].X) / 2;
            p.X += polygon.Points[(int)TagId.Start].X;
            p.Y = polygon.Points[(int)TagId.FadeInEnd].Y;

            thumb = (Thumb)thumbArrray[polygon.Points.Count];
            thumb.Arrange(new Rect(p.X, p.Y, 14, 17));

            p.X += 15;
            thumb = (Thumb)thumbArrray[polygon.Points.Count+1];
            thumb.Arrange(new Rect(p.X, p.Y, 15, 9));
        }
        return finalSize;
    }

    private void BuildCorner(ref Thumb thumb, Cursor tempCursor, int id)
    {
        thumb.Height = 20;
        thumb.Width = 30;

        thumb.Cursor = tempCursor;
        Style style;
        if (id == (int)TagId.Direction)
        {
            // build style in code so we can bind the mouse click
            thumb.Height = 30;

            var s =new Style();

            var grid = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Grid));

            var label = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));

            label.SetValue(Label.ContentProperty, "<>");
            label.SetValue(Label.FontSizeProperty, 9d);
            label.SetValue(Label.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(0));
            label.SetValue(Label.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Verdana"));
            label.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonDownEvent,  new MouseButtonEventHandler(DirectionThumbClick));

            grid.AppendChild(label);

            var ct = new ControlTemplate(typeof(Thumb)) { VisualTree = grid };

            s.Setters.Add(new Setter(MainWindow.TemplateProperty, ct));
            style = s;

        }
        else
        {
            if ((id == (int)TagId.Start) || (id == (int)TagId.FadeInEnd) || (id == (int)TagId.FadeInMag))
            {
                style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ThumbStyleLeft"];
            }
            else if (id == (int)TagId.Middle)
            {
                thumb.Height = 17;
                thumb.Width = 14;
                style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ThumbStyle"];
            }
            else
            {
                style = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["ThumbStyleRight"];
            }
        }
        thumb.Style = style;
        thumb.Opacity = 0.80;

        visualChildren.Add(thumb);
    }

    private void attachAdorners(Polygon polygon)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= polygon.Points.Count+1; i++)
        {
            var p = new Point();
            var thumb = new Thumb();
            Cursor tempCursor = null;

            if (i < polygon.Points.Count)
            {
                p = polygon.Points[i];
            }

            switch (i)
            {
                case (int)TagId.Start:
                case (int)TagId.End:
                    tempCursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                    break;
                case (int)TagId.FadeOutStart:
                case (int)TagId.FadeInEnd:
                    tempCursor = Cursors.SizeNWSE;
                    break;
                case (int)TagId.FadeOutMag:
                case (int)TagId.FadeInMag:
                    tempCursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                    break;
                case (int)TagId.Middle:
                    tempCursor = Cursors.Hand;
                    break;
                case (int)TagId.Direction:
                    tempCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
                    thumb.MouseRightButtonDown += this.DirectionThumbClick;
                    break;
            }

            BuildCorner(ref thumb, tempCursor, i);

            thumb.Tag = i;
            thumb.DragDelta += this.ThumbDragDelta;
            thumb.MouseEnter += this.ThumbOnMouseEnter;

            thumbArrray.Add(thumb);
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is the code where I attach the thumbs(adorners) to the polygon:

```
private void Polygon_DoubleClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
if (e.OriginalSource is Shape)
{
    UIElement uie = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
    Polygon p = e.OriginalSource as Polygon;

    if (p != null)
    {
        var tag = p.Tag as TimelineTag;
        //TimelineCollection is an ObservableCollection<>
        TimelineCollection collection = this.GetCollectionBasedOnTagLevel(tag);

        if (tag != null && ((TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id)).IsEditing)
        {
            AdornerLayer adornerlayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(uie);

            p.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(000, 000, 000));
            Adorner[] toRemoveArray = adornerlayer.GetAdorners(uie);
            if (toRemoveArray != null)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < toRemoveArray.Length; x++)
                {
                    adornerlayer.Remove(toRemoveArray[x]);
                }
            }
            ((TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id)).IsEditing = false;
            selectedPolygon = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (tag != null)
            {
                if (((TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id)).Type == TimelineItem.TimelineItemType.Axis)
                {
                    var sel = new AxisSelectionAdorners(
                        uie, (TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id), this.TimelineGrid);
                    p.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));

                    AdornerLayer adornerlayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(uie);
                    adornerlayer.Add(sel);
                }
                else if (((TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id)).Type
                            == TimelineItem.TimelineItemType.Square)
                {
                    var sel = new SquareSelectionAdorners(
                        uie, (TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id), this.TimelineGrid);
                    p.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 255));

                    AdornerLayer adornerlayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(uie);
                    adornerlayer.Add(sel);
                }
                ((TimelineItem)collection.ElementAt(tag.Id)).IsEditing = true;
                selectedPolygon = p;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but where are you using/creating an instance of Thumb?

Comment: Have you tried {TemplateBinding DataContext.TestingLabel} ?

Comment: Trying that I get a compile time error : Cannot resolve symbol 'DataContext'

The thumbs are created when the user double clicks on the polygon.
I have edited my question to include the code for applying styles to the thumbs.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand where in the visual tree the Thumbs are located. In your code I can't find what visualChildren is and where it is located
Ex: How are your Thumb instances related with each Polygon in the visual tree?

Comment: Daniel, sorry bout that.  I have attached my code where I attach the thumbs to the polygon's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's not a complete answer but it fits my needs.

I don't need to go down into the polygon's data, since these values are not data values, they are computed values. They don't need to be in my "data layer" they can be computed values in my adorner class.

I accomplished this by putting the

```
public String TestingLabel { get { return "test"; } }
```

in my `AxisSelectionAdorners` Class.
Then bind with xaml like so:

```
{Binding TestingLabel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Timeline:AxisSelectionAdorners}}}
```

This is testing code, Converter and such can be hooked up as needed.